# How to transfer my local/development datastore to the real/deployment datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, datastore

How to transfer my local/development datastore to the real/deployment datastore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's surprisingly complex, but you can use the bulk uploader to accomplish this.  See http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html

You use the bulk loader to download the data from your development store and then upload it to your production store.

Comment: Oh... ok.. still so I dont know how to do this: "After adding the builtins directive, you need to update your app with the revised app.yaml:
appcfg.py update <app-directory>" from your link. Im using aptana, pydev

Comment: @Totty: using an IDE is great, but you will do yourself a huge favor getting to know the very small and basic set of commandline utilities that come with AppEngine. You can find out more about the appcfg.py utility and general management procedures here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp.html

Comment: Are you using python or Java?